# server directory lookup in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server

server directory lookup in sql server 2008 are showing D:\xyz\ but there is no d: drive. So I want to change server directory lookup so that .mdf and .log files of my database store in c:\

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very unclear and it's probably one for the DBA site anyway, but here are some comments:

- If you are asking "how do I change the default location for new database files?", you can do it [using SSMS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd206993.aspx)
- If you are asking "how do I move existing database files to another location?" then this process is described in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189133.aspx)

Whatever your question really is, I strongly suggest that you do not put these files in the root of the C: drive (C:\) because it creates permissions/security issues and is non-standard and therefore confusing for developers and even some tools. Of course, perhaps you meant you want to use a subfolder somewhere on C:, but you still need to be aware of the permissions issues. If you haven't already done so, you should review the documentation on [default file locations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143547.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. actually I am installing hMailserver on one of server windows 2008 r2. it has only one drive c:\. When trying to installing hMailServer it gives error like server lookup directory not found. It finding d:\ but we have not d:\ So I have to change it

Comment: @AkilVhora If your problem is hMailServer installation, then it has nothing to do with SQL Server; "server lookup directory" is not a standard SQL Server term. You might get a better answer if you submit a new question about hMailServer, but if you do, please mention the exact error message you see.